# Is there a way to connect to Kafka on an Azure virtual machine using port 80 or 443? If not, why?

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, virtual-machine

I would like to connect to Kafka using port 80 on my Azure virtual machine. I installed Java and Kafka on the virtual machine. I added inbound port rule for port 80.

[image: my inbound rules]

I added port=80 to Kafka’s config/server.properties file. I ran zookeeper succesfully.

When I try to connect to kafka I get this error:

> ERROR [KafkaServer id=0] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
> org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Socket server failed to bind to 0.0.0.0:80: Permission denied

[image: error]

I can connect to kafka using other ports, I tried 9092, 8000, 8080, 4430

But I can’t connect to it using port 80 or 443. The problem is I want to access Kafka using port 80 or 443 because I want to produce messages using a web server which is only allowed to use port 80 or 443.

Why can’t I connect to kafka using port 80 on an Azure virtual machine?

Comment: Kafka is not an HTTP service, why bind to 80 or 443 at all? Your web server only having outbound traffic to certain ports seems more the issue than the Kafka server

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. I want to produce messages to Kafka through my Azure web app. (I wrote web server by mistake) I read somewhere that Azure web apps don't have a port mapping feature. Only port 80 and 443 are open. I know I can run Kafka on port 80 on my local machine, so I wondered why I can't do it on an Azure VM. BTW I'm probably going to use Azure Functions to communicate between Kafka on Confluent cloud and my web app.

Comment: Your Azure web app should be able to send data out on any of port to produce to an external Kafka endpoint. If you are getting "permission denied", then only Azure support could really answer that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my knowledge, you can do the same things you did in your local machine. So you can connect the Kafka that configured in the VM using the port 80. And as the error shows, the problem is the permission. You need to check the permission of the Kafka or the User you use to configure the Kafka.

And for the Web App, it only can expose one port to the outside world, and the ports must be 80 or 443. But your application can listen to any ports inside the Web App, then you just need to set the environment variable `WEBSITES_PORT` for the port. Azure will route the requests outside from the port 80 to the port your application listens to. See the issue [My custom container listens to a port other than port 80. How can I configure my app to route requests to that port?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/faq-app-service-linux#custom-containers)